# Spotfire - Range Filter Scale broken

Tags: spotfire

I have made a dashboard in SF which is working fine, with several range filters which have a log scale.

I have changed the data source and the dashboard is fine except for the log scaled range filters. I now cannot change the scale of these to log, which is problematic.

Any ideas would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Does your new data source have negative values?

Comment: No, I think the issue may be to do with the formats in the source data. I am currently trying to resolve it with this in mind

Comment: make sure that the column's datatype is correctly set. if not, you can add a transformation to change it. if that's not the issue, please post some sample data and I'll see if I can reproduce the problem.